# futures_klines working vs get_klines getting error Not all sent parameters were read; read '3' parameter(s) but was sent '4'

Tags: python, client, binance

I'm using the Binance client in python to get klines data which works fine for the futures call but I need to use the spot data for other symbols not available on futures. any ideas how to fix this?  the online examples look to be the same but for some reason it says only 3 params not 4 allowed. what are the 3?

```
    from binance.client import Client
    binance = Client(api_key=binance_api_key, api_secret=binance_api_secret)

    df_check=check_binanceklines(symbol=symbol)


    def check_binanceklines(symbol='BTCUSDT',interval='1m',limit=60,since="1 hour ago UTC"):
        klines = binance.futures_klines(symbol=symbol,interval={'1m':Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE}[interval],since=since,limit=limit)
    ***# issue below!***
        klines = binance.get_klines(symbol=symbol,interval={'1m':Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE}[interval],since=since,limit=limit) 




    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "binance-test.py", line 254, in <module>
        df_check=check_binanceklines(symbol=symbol) # get 1 hour ago, every minute
      File "binance-test.py", line 29, in check_binanceklines
        klines = binance.get_klines(symbol=symbol,interval=        {'1m':Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE}[interval],since=since,limit=limit)
      File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-        packages\binance\client.py", line 868, in get_klines
        return self._get('klines', data=params, version=self.PRIVATE_API_VERSION)
      File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-        packages\binance\client.py", line 371, in _get
        return self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-        packages\binance\client.py", line 334, in _request_api
        return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 315, in _request
        return self._handle_response(self.response)
      File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 324, in _handle_response
        raise BinanceAPIException(response, response.status_code, response.text)
    binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1104): Not all sent parameters were read; read '3' parameter(s) but was sent '4'.
```

Answer (score 3):

`binance.client.Client.get_klines()` can be called with the following parameters:

```sh
Signature: Client.get_klines(self, **params) -> Dict
Docstring:
Kline/candlestick bars for a symbol. Klines are uniquely identified by their open time.

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#kline-candlestick-data

:param symbol: required
:type symbol: str
:param interval: -
:type interval: str
:param limit: - Default 500; max 1000.
:type limit: int
:param startTime:
:type startTime: int
:param endTime:
:type endTime: int

:returns: API response
```

Therefore `since` is an invalid parameter. Use `startTime` or `endTime` instead. These parameters ask for a timestamp in milliseconds. Here is a working example which gives you the last 60 minutes (including the current minute):

```py
import datetime as dt

from binance.client import Client


def check_binanceklines(
        symbol = 'BTCUSDT',
        interval = Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE,
        limit = 60,
        end = int(dt.datetime.now(dt.timezone.utc).timestamp() * 1000)
):
    binance = Client()
    return binance.get_klines(symbol=symbol,interval=interval,endTime=end,limit=limit)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    klines = check_binanceklines()

    # Print len, the first and last elemnt of returned klines list.
    print(f'Length of the returned klines list: {len(klines)}')
    print(klines[1])
    print(klines[-1])
```

Output:

```sh
Length of the returned klines list: 60
[1647377880000, '39416.16000000', '39418.45000000', '39377.71000000', '39389.27000000', '25.79166000', 1647377939999, '1016095.94556700', 951, '8.45500000', '333088.81485350', '0']
[1647381360000, '39613.93000000', '39642.67000000', '39611.01000000', '39632.97000000', '14.80226000', 1647381419999, '586574.96479330', 452, '7.66347000', '303656.99947290', '0']
```